# Flutter app is not opening in physical device(Iqoo Z7) in debug mode

Tags: flutter, usb-debugging

I have enabled use debugging,still not able to run the app in my handset which is Iqoo Z7 in debug mode.
Earlier I used to run the same application on my samsung a10 handset using usb debugging.
I have tried everything, but still the app is getting stucked on white blank screen.
Also I can't see any error in debug console or terminal.

USB debugging is on
Updated my flutter version
ran every command like flutter clean, deleting build etc.

Comment: the mmi code to open bbklog for one click authorization does not work for me. dialing *#*#112#*#* does nothing for me. The vivo developer agent said "If it does not have any respond after dialing that means your device can not be enabled one -click authorization."

Answer (score 0):

contact vivo developer, by email, wechat, or whatsapp, i personally went through whatsapp, it takes time until they respond(2 days in my cases), just state that you're developer and want develop stuff blah3, and say you need "one click authorization", for what is that here's a complete explanation https://siwing.github.io/Flutter/Vivo%20phone%20system%20log%20output%20problem.html

Comment: the mmi code to open bbklog for one click authorization does not work for me. dialing *#*#112#*#* does nothing for me. The vivo developer agent said "If it does not have any respond after dialing that means your device can not be enabled one -click authorization."

Comment: please tell if that worked for you or not